# Key to value using jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I need to transform multiple keys and their values to new JSON spec using jolt.

Input:

```json
{
  "product": "monitor",
  "ID": "222",
  "price": "300"
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "record": [
    {
      "key": "product",
      "value": "monitor"
    },
    {
      "key": "ID",
      "value": "222"
    },
    {
      "key": "price",
      "value": "300"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Convert each node in the input json into key/value and shift to the named object. And then named object is moved to the array.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&1.value",
        "$": "&1.key"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "records"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just another example and essentially the same than the previous answer but with more comments:

**input**

```
{
  "foo": "foo value",
  "bar": "bar value",
  "zoo": "zoo value"
}
```

**jolt spec**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "foo|bar" : { // pick only these names, other names (i.e. zoo) are filtered
        // $ current name (LHS) (i.e. foo or bar)
        // @ current value (LHS) (i.e. "foo value" of "bar value")
        // & current name (RHS) (i.e. foo or bar)
        "$": "&.key",
        "@": "&.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // iterate all top level names (i.e. foo or bar)
        // copy only the values (@), e.g.:
        //   {
        //     "key" : "foo",
        //     "value" : "foo value"
        //   }
        // under a new name (records). [] is redundant but more descriptive
        "@": "records[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**output after the first transformation**

```
{
  "foo" : {
    "key" : "foo",
    "value" : "foo value"
  },
  "bar" : {
    "key" : "bar",
    "value" : "bar value"
  }
}
```

**the final output (after the second transformation)**

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "key": "foo",
      "value": "foo value"
    },
    {
      "key": "bar",
      "value": "bar value"
    }
  ]
}
```